# How are ones and zeroes stored in a computer physically?

Tags: digital-logic, memory

As I mentioned in the title "physically", when the computer is off and there is no power, how are the bits stored? For example, how can an image be stored?

Comment: Hard drives and flash memory, types of nonvolatile storage, are used to store bits when power is off.   Are you asking how each of these work?  Any specific one?

Comment: What has your research showed so far?

Answer (score 12):

Zeros and ones may be stored as different orientation of a magnetic field stored in a ferromagnetic media such as disks or tapes.

They may be stored as an electric field in semiconductors in the gate oxide of field effect transistors.

Another method are holes in an opaque layer of a disc read out by a laser beam used for DVD.

A very old method but still used in the seventies are punched holes in paper tapes or cards.

Between about 1955 and 1975 core memories were used. The cores were small toroidal rings of magnetic material. They were read and written by electric currents flowing through wires threaded through the cores. The data was stored in a powered down computer too.

Comment: Nice, succinct answer without delving into some of the more esoteric methods.

Comment: Just one thought.  When you edit your answer you should at least call attention to your edit so previous viewers know that there have been changes made.

Answer (score 4):

Computers use some sort of **nonvolatile storage** to provide and preserve state during power-off and while running.

Common types of nonvolatile storage in use today include:

- hard disk, which uses magnetic media with zones magnetized to represent ones and zeros
- Flash memory (NAND and/or NOR), which stores ones and zeros as permanently-charged capacitors (‘floating gates’)
- EPROM / EEPROM are earlier cousins of flash that also use floating-gate capacitors
- ROM are chips with the program hard encoded in the silicon, as blown fuses (PROM) or bits defined a mask during chip fabrication (mask ROM)

I’ll add a couple of others you might read or heard about:

- [ferroelectric memory (FRAM)](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/memories/f-ram-ferroelectric-ram/) for specialty applications like automotive. FRAM offers a large number of write cycles like RAM but isn’t subject to wear-out like flash or EEPROM. Think applications like odometers and hour meters.
- Battery-backed SRAM, used in the past for PCs. It has largely been supplanted by NOR flash or EEPROM, with the battery only powering a clock chip.

In the future?

- [Magnetic RAM (MRAM)](https://www.mram-info.com/introduction), also known as 'spintronic' RAM, is a hot area of research nowadays. It has the potential to replace ordinary silicon RAM memory with a lower-power, yet nonvolatile solution.
- [Memristors](https://www.memristor.org/reference/research/13/what-are-memristors) are a new kind of device that ‘remember’ currents passing through them, and so offer the potential to store nonvolatile state.

In the past there have been many, very creative solutions for nonvolatile storage. Two widely-used ones were [magnetic core memory](https://nationalmaglab.org/education/magnet-academy/watch-play/interactive/magnetic-core-memory-tutorial), [punch cards](https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/object-groups/punch-cards), or [punched paper tape](https://codedocs.org/what-is/punched-tape).

Answer (score 3):

It's not so difficult in concept. Any physical thing that can be constructed where you can put it between two or more states can be used as memory. All you need is a device that can detect the state and convert it into a signal the rest of the computer can use (which would just be an electrical signal for modern computers). Whether that be dark and light spots, high and low pits, strong or weak magnetic fields, or charge and no charge.

So really, you could use stone tablet and dig holes into it to represent zeroes or ones and not holes to represent the other state. As long as you have a machine that can run over the tablet with a sensor to detect the holes and not holes.

On an optical disc like a CD or DVD it is pits or dark and light spots. On a hard drive it is the strength or polarity of the magnetic field. In flash memory or SSD it is whether or not there is charge. In the past it was whether or not a wire was threaded through a toroidal core.

You could also conceivably use vinyl records to store digital data as well. You just interpret the grooves on the record digitally. Same goes for magnetic tapes (which actually is used for digital storage).

Comment: The core rope memories used in the Apollo guidance computer did not use knots to store the program, the sense wires were threaded through cores or aside the cores.

Comment: @Uwe Is that how it was?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_rope_memory

Comment: Capacitance electronic discs used a 30cm conductive vinyl substrate to store 60 minutes of NTSC video per side: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance_Electronic_Disc.  It used a stylus-in-groove similar to LP records but since the bandwidth was orders of magnitude higher, it used the capacitance between the stylus and disc to read the data off the physical shape of the track.

Comment: @vir Oh yeah. I heard about those off the Youtube channel Technology Connections.

Answer (score 2):

> `"... stored physically"`

implies a medium.

- On RAM chips, 1/0 are most likely stored on (trench) capacitors; Memory is addressable in groups of bits.
- On a SSD drive, a host of non-volatile technologies are used. Search for NAND Flash for instance.
- On a Hard drive (rotational/traditional) a magnetic platter can store 1/0 by aligning magnetic particles using a floating head. A complex mechanism of error detection/correction can read information back with integrity.
- On computational circuits, the architecture of a typical storage cell is a D-flip-flop also known as a D-register.
- Back in the days of relay storage, the physical position of the relay stored information (just like an on/off switch).
- On a magnetic tape, it is done by aligning magnetic particles.
- On a paper tape (punched card), it could be the absence or presence of a hole.

Comment: Question was "when the computer is off and there is no power, how are the bits stored?" so D-flip-flops, (trench) capacitors and relays do not count.